# Angular 2 Call Function After For Each

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript, foreach

I'm making an api call in a for each loop in angular 2. Once all of the calls are made I want to call another function that redirects the user via router.

This is what I have so far:

```
processData(){
var itemsToMove = this.myArray.length;

this.myArray.forEach((item:any, index:any) => {

let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

//code that sets up my urlSearchParam
let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
itemsToMove--;

this.putService.putObjectWithBody("myapicall", body).subscribe(data => {
 if (itemsToMove === 0) {
 this.redirect();
  }
});
}
}
```

Is there a better way that I can ensure that the async data is processed before calling `this.redirect()`? This works, but it seems inefficient and messy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for this situation; it runs all observable sequences in parallel  before going into the callback. So for this you need an array of observables.

```
processData(){      
  var observableArray:any = [];
  this.myArray.forEach((item:any, index:any) => {

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    //code that sets up my urlSearchParam
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

    observableArray.push( this.putService.putObjectWithBody("myapicall", body) );
  }

  Observable.forkJoin(observableArray)
        .subscribe(data => {
            //this.myFunction(data[0], data[1]...);
            this.redirect();
        });
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: @Bhetzie Glad I could help!